# PHP $_GET problems with www.example.com/folder/file?id=2 type URLs

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm changing my site to show friendly URLs like this:

```
www.example.com/folder/topic
```

Works fine!

But when I add a parameter to the URL:

```
www.example.com/folder/topic?page=2
```

`$_GET` stops working. It doesn't recognise the parameter at all. Am I missing something? The parameter worked fine before using full URLs.

Answer (score 9):

If it's a mod_rewrite problem, which it sounds like, you could add the `[QSA]` flag to your mod_rewrite rule, to append the query string to the rewritten URL instead of throwing it away.

Your rule will end up looking like:

`RewriteRule from to [QSA]`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mod_rewrite then it is your rules that are broken.  Either the query string is not being passed, or the mod_rewrite is discarding everything past **/topic**.

Try adding a rule that you can do: **www.example.com/folder/topic/2**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your PHP URLs "friendly" you need to use something like Apache's mod_rewrite.  Google something like "apache mod_write friendly url" and you will get plenty of articles on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm changing my site to show friendly URLs

Are you doing this using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or by reorganising your file structure? If the former, it's likely that your rules may need tweaking.

If it's a file re-organisation, what do you get when you `print_r($_GET)` in `www.example.com/folder/topic?page=2`?

Answer (score 0):

MrZebra's answer is the correct one. It will allow you to continue to use query string as you do at the end of a URL, and you don't have to anticipate its presence one way or the other.